# PhP: Merge arrays with matching keys and delete / remove extra non-matching values

Tags: php, arrays, merge, key, key-value

I'd like to merge these two arrays based on their key, and only keep the key matches. The merged array should retain the key, and the value should come from the second array.

**Array #1: States I've Visited**

```
Array
(
    [AL] => 113
    [AZ] => 83
    [CA] => 50
    [CO] => 1
...
```

**Array #2: All States**

```
Array
(
    [AL] => ALABAMA
    [AK] => ALASKA
    [AZ] => ARIZONA
    [AR] => ARKANSAS
    [CA] => CALIFORNIA
    [CO] => COLORADO
    [CT] => CONNECTICUT
...
```

So, If I've been to a state, I'd like to get the name of that state from Array 2. And throw out any non-matching nodes from array #2.

**Desired Result**

```
Array
(
    [AL] => ALABAMA
    [AZ] => ARIZONA
    [CA] => CALIFORNIA
    [CO] => COLORADO
...
```

I've done extensive research in the PHP manual and on StackOverflow, and cannot find a particular answer to this.  I think it probably lies in a more complex user defined function than I am capable of at this point.

`array_merge()` almost does what I want, but then it adds the states I have not visited to the end of the array

`array_intersect_key()` also gets close.  It keeps only the matching keys, but then it gets rid of values.

Comment: Your problem with [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) is probably that you have your arrays in the wrong order. It keeps the values from the first array it's passed, so you want array #2 as the first argument then array #1 as the second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enjoy this mildly inefficient example while I write a better solution. http://codepad.org/hIjPEM81

**Inefficient Solution 1:**

```
<?php
$allstates=array("MO"=>"Missouri", "TX"=>"Texas");
$statesIveBeenTo = array("MO"=>1);
foreach($allstates as $k=>$v){
  if(!array_key_exists($k,$statesIveBeenTo)){
    unset($allstates[$k]);
  }
}

var_dump($allstates);
```

**Outputs:**

```
array(1) {
  ["MO"]=>
  string(8) "Missouri"
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
$test = array_intersect_key($allstates, $statesIveBeenTo);
var_dump($test);
```

The same output as above.

Comment: First, thank you!  Inefficient does everything I need it to. However, after hours at the helm, I never thought of flipping the arrays in array_intersect_key().  I was using array_intersect_key($statesIveBeenTo,$allstates); It is all part of the learning curve.

Comment: ... and reading the manual. (Okay, there's no way to keep that terse comment from sounding condescending, so I offer this disclaimer that I do not intend for it to be condescending. lol) In all seriousness, it is often easier to devise a solution when you have a more specific understanding of exactly what a function does or how it works.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and not being condescending. I read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) before and after the solution.  I guess I was just so stuck on array 1 being the one to merge to, that I did not think of the solution this way. When I'm on hour 3, is when I need to collaborate with humans.